# React - componente hijo dinamico

Tags: reactjs

Muy buenas a todos y espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un componente llamado **Contenido** el cual debe ser capaz de recibir para luego mostrar según la acción del usuario uno u otro componente, mi pregunta es, Cómo hago para mostrar un componente hijo dinámico y cuál seria la mejor práctica para ello?.

EL componente contenido es así según **React** en su parte de **Containment**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Contenido extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Contenido
```

y esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora en el componente que importa al componente **Contenido**:

```
render () {
    return (
        < Contenido>
          < Publicaciones/>
        < /Contenido>
    )
  }
```

Cabe resaltar si se dan cuenta que dentro de **Contenido** paso otro componente llamado **Publicaciones**, la idea es pasar allí componente dinamicamente, por defecto seria **Publicaciones** pero imaginen que el usuario da click en un menú y debería de mostrarse otro componente allí.

Seria algo como asi:

```
render () {
    return (
        < Contenido>
          < Publicaciones/> 
          ó
          < OtroComponente/>
          ó
          < OtroComponente/>
          ó
          ...
        < /Contenido>
    )
  }
```

Espero me sepa explicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución, la idea es hacer una función fuera de la clase principal del componente e invocarla pasandole un props donde luego esa función según el valor del props pasado evaluará que componente va a mostrar en el render, quedaría algo como esto:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { componente1, componente2, componente3 } from '../src/components';
    class Contenido extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          contenido: 1//Aqui es el valor que le pasare al props de la función
        };

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <LayoutContendio contenido={this.state.contenido} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    function LayoutContendio(props) {

     switch(props.contenido) {

      case 1: return <componente1/>; break;
      case 2: return <componente2/>; break;
      case 3: return <componente3/>; break;
      default: return <componente1/>; break;

    } 

  }
  export default Contenido
```

Si se fijan cree un **state** que inicialmente le coloque valor 1 para darle un valor por defecto y ese valor mostrará el **componente1** pero si el usuario hace un click y cambia el **state** a 2 mostraría el **componente2** y así sucesivamente, espero les sirva